# Exchange data between Vue3 components with an emitter and redirecting to another route

Tags: redirect, vuejs3, vue-component, eventemitter

My first Vue3 component has a button. When pressing that button data should be sent to another component that is a child component of the second component. Afterwards it should be redirected to another page on which the data should be displayed.

```
export default {
  name: 'Text Field',
  inject: ['emitter'],
  data(){
    return{
      searchText: '',
      locations: [],
      initialCoordinates: [139.753, 35.6844],
  }
},
methods: {
// other methods skipped
submit() {
    this.initialCoordinates = [longitude, latitude]

    this.emitter.emit('Coordinates', this.initialCoordinates)
    
    this.$router.push('/test');
  },
// rest of the component
```

In the child component of the second component I try to receive the data from the emitter before it is redirected to the other page including the component.

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "test_emitter",
    inject: ["emitter"],
    mounted(){
      this.emitter.on('Coordinates', (coordinates) => {
      alert('test' + coordinates)
    });
    }
}
</script>
```

But the alert 'test' in the child of the second component is never shown even though the event is emitted from the first component.

I thought it has something to do with the redirection but no logging or alerts are shown indicating that the data was received at any time.

I have also tested the same emitter configuration without redirection and with emitting the data to a child component of the current component at the same route and it works. So I would be happy about any tips or advice :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using Vue Router's beforeRouteLeave guard:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'newRoute', query: { coordinates: this.coordinates } });
```

Doing so I can route to another page and simultaniously provide data to the component that is routed to.